# Ansible memtotal_mb fact is undefined

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to run this play in Ansible but it is complaining that the variable `ansible_memtotal_mb` is undefined.  This is the play that is failing for me

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - debug:  
        msg: "{{ ansible_memtotal_mb }}"
```

despite `gather_facts` being set to `yes` in the play.

After more investigation I discovered that I can see the fact using `ansible host -m setup` on my targeted host, yet it is undefined in the play.

I am using `ansible-core 2.12.1`. Here is some information about the targeted OS:

```
Linux serverName 5.11.0-1025-aws #27~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 7 13:09:56 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and the targeted machine is an AWS EC2 instance of Ubuntu.

The facts gathered via

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - debug:
         msg: "{{ ansible_facts }}"
```

are only

```
{'cmdline': {'BOOT_IMAGE': '/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-1025-aws', 'root': 'PARTUUID=24ca9e81-01', 'ro': True, 'console': 'ttyS0', 'nvme_core.io_timeout': '4294967295', 'panic': '-1'}, 'proc_cmdline': {'BOOT_IMAGE': '/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-1025-aws', 'root': 'PARTUUID=24ca9e81-01', 'ro': True, 'console': ['tty1', 'ttyS0'], 'nvme_core.io_timeout': '4294967295', 'panic': '-1'}, 'dns': {'nameservers': ['127.0.0.1'], 'search': ['us-west-2.compute.internal', 'node.ca1.consul', 'node.us1.consul']}, 'selinux_python_present': True, 'selinux': {'status': 'disabled'},

'lsb': {'id': 'Ubuntu', 'description': 'Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS', 'release': '20.04', 'codename': 'focal', 'major_release': '20'}, 'system_capabilities_enforced': 'True', 'system_capabilities': [''], 'distribution': 'Ubuntu', 'distribution_release': 'focal', 'distribution_version': '20.04', 'distribution_major_version': '20', 'distribution_file_path': '/etc/os-release', 'distribution_file_variety': 'Debian', 'distribution_file_parsed': True, 'os_family': 'Debian', 'ansible_local': {}, 'fips': False, 'apparmor': {'status': 'enabled'}, 'python': {'version': {'major': 3, 'minor': 8, 'micro': 10, 'releaselevel': 'final', 'serial': 0}, 'version_info': [3, 8, 10, 'final', 0], 'executable': '/usr/bin/python3.8', 'has_sslcontext': True, 'type': 'cpython'}, 'system': 'Linux', 'kernel': '5.11.0-1025-aws', 'kernel_version': '#27~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 7 13:09:56 UTC 2022', 'machine': 'x86_64', 'python_version': '3.8.10', 'fqdn': 'private', 'hostname': 'private', 'nodename': 'private', 'domain': '', 'userspace_bits': '64', 'architecture': 'x86_64', 'userspace_architecture': 'x86_64', 'machine_id': 'private', 'pkg_mgr': 'apt', 'service_mgr': 'systemd', 'gather_subset': ['!hardware'], 'module_setup': True}`
```

but according [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) it was expected to see something like

```json
    "ansible_memfree_mb": 7709,
    "ansible_memory_mb": {
        "nocache": {
            "free": 7804,
            "used": 173
        },
        "real": {
            "free": 7709,
            "total": 7977,
            "used": 268
        },
        "swap": {
            "cached": 0,
            "free": 0,
            "total": 0,
            "used": 0
        }
    },
    "ansible_memtotal_mb": 7977,
```

Please, any information on this bizarre issue is welcomed.

Comment: `I am trying to run this play` <= you are only showing a single isolated task. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70777188/edit) your question and paste a full minimal playbook (a single play with the defined `hosts` target and that current single task should do) and the full output you get. See [creating an MCVE](/help/mcve)

Comment: Works for me (Ubuntu 18.04, ansible 2.10.11) ``shell> ansible localhost -m setup | grep memtotal`` gives ``"ansible_memtotal_mb": 7676``. The same command in (Ubuntu 20.04, ansible [core 2.12.1]) gives ``"ansible_memtotal_mb": 7825``. [edit] the question and make it [mre].

Comment: I did also some testing and wasn't able to reproduce the issue. It was just working as expected. Since it is working several other environments and almost no information is given, this seems to be currently not reproducible. @MasterLuke, should provide more information.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of information I had been struggling all day with it and fired my question into the web without much thought.  I have added a full play that recreates the issue and the target machine's basic info.  Let me know if there is other info that is useful.

Comment: From your description it is already clear what is **not** there but expected. Regarding "_Let me know if there is other info that is useful_", can you edit your question and add the full output of `msg: {{ ansible_facts }}` so that it is clear what **is** actually gathered?

Comment: I have added some of the facts

Comment: @MasterLuke, what means "_some of the fatcs_"? I've expeced something like [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts). However, within your provided output is set via `gather_subset': ['!hardware']` not to gather the value in question. Where is that [`parameter`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#parameter-gather_subset) coming from?

Comment: @MasterLuke, according [`module_utils/facts/hardware/linux.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/hardware/linux.py#L115), the `memory_facts` are `hardware_facts`.

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying but what i listed is the output from this play
```- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - debug:  
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts }}"
```

Comment: you are saying that the gather_subset is not set to gather the hardware values such as memtotal?

Comment: @MasterLuke, thanks for confirming that the output is the full output of `ansible_facts`. Within that full output  a parameter is reported which configures to **not** gather hardware facts including memory facts. Means , somewhere in your configuration the gathering of `ansible_mem*` is disabled.

Comment: Ah perhaps this line in my ansible.cfg is doing that lol
```
gather_subset = !hardware
```
I think we can consider this solved
thanks for your help with this

Comment: @MasterLuke, right, if you set within `ansible.cfg` the parameter `gather_subset = !hardware`, than it will disable the gathering of `hardware_facts` including memory information.

Answer (score 3):

After some investigation in the gathered facts and finding

```json
    "gather_subset": [
        "!hardware"
    ],
    "module_setup": true
}
```

it turned out that there was a [parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#parameter-gather_subset) set in the `ansible.cfg` file to

```
gather_subset = !hardware
```

and which was preventing Ansible from collecting the memory information by default, since `memory_facts` are `hardware_facts` according [module_utils/facts/hardware/linux.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/hardware/linux.py#L115).

Removing the configuration line returned Ansible to its default behaviour.

Comment: Please don't use answers to summarize fixes. Please go through the [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [ask] and [answer] and their linked pages.

Comment: @theTinMan: Can you clarify what you mean? Isn't the _exact_ purpose of answers to "summarize fixes"? Is your point that answers should, ideally, not _just_ include the fix, but also an _explanation_?

Comment: Answers are for solutions that solved the problem, not summaries. If *you* solved it, without help, then your answer should be the accepted solution. If that's not what happened, then select the one that helped and upvote it. The person submitting the solution is supposed to explain how it works and why it's the right solution; We're trying to educate so people know how to solve similar problems in the future, not just this problem now.

Comment: See "[Should you put an answer to your own question and mark it as the accepted answer or update your question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271399/128421)"
and
"[Are answers which merely summarize other answers acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300586/128421)"